# Persist flash animation on page browsing?

Tags: html, flash, persistence, playback, continuous

Is it possible to have flash animation work uninterrupted on my site (in some overlay at the border of the browser) while user browses my site pages?

The only way I see is to put animation onto `<frame>` but the geometry of such layout is very limited.

Are there any solutions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framing is really your only option here. You will lose everything when the user navigates to another page.

Comment: Is it possible for webpage to know if it has a frame or not and automatically reopen itself in latter case? Is it possible to create transparent or non-rectangular frames?